# Obeo Desinger dont start on windows 11

Tags: eclipse, crash, sirius

I want to run Obeo Designer, on windows 11 and jvm 8 (1.8.0:331) installed. When I run obeodesigner.exe, it crash and show me this errors
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tw1hK.jpg
Could anybody tell me how can I solve it?

Comment: You should probably contact the developers.

Comment: Looks like you have a 32 bit Java but the code requires 64 bit Java.

Comment: I also check the installed jvm, and it is 64 bit,